# AWK replacing tabs in last column with conditions

Tags: awk

I'm trying to work with a dataset that contains tabs as delimiters, but the last column has a custom field where users are able to enter custom text, including tabs. Now I'm trying to delete those tabs using

```
awk "/\t/{c++;if(c==7){sub(\"\t\",\"\");c=0}}1" users10000.csv >users10000awk.csv
```

but it seems like there is no delimiter between the 6th and 7th column is the 7th is empty.

What I'm now trying to do is only replace tabs found after the 7th if the last field is not empty through

```
awk /\t/{c++;if((c==7) && ($12!=\"\")){sub(\"\t\",\"\");c=0;}}1 usersorig.csv >usersorigawk.csv
```

but this results in the error

```
){sub(\"\t\" was unexpected at this time.
```

I'm completely new to AWK and was hoping to get it to easily work, but the formatting is a pain to get used to. Any chance you could help?

Sample input:

```
100008949   esttrellitta    264 44  6853    0   28 Dec 2009 18:01:42 GMT    El Paso,Tx.
100009841   ChelseaBex  152 50  394 0   28 Dec 2009 18:05:43 GMT    
100012792   ErinPattisonn   984 666 5003    0   28 Dec 2009 18:19:39 GMT    under your bed.
100013967   TUBeautifulRosa 323 251 1269    0   28 Dec 2009 18:24:51 GMT    on  Twitter ....... ahaahaa !
100014135   GeenaJohnson    144 130 9789    0   28 Dec 2009 18:25:37 GMT    Arkansas
100015928   GooSau  93  286 8075    0   28 Dec 2009 18:33:59 GMT    
10001882    rjwilson    1   340 6358    0   6 Nov 2007 15:54:47 GMT iPhone: 39.053871, 95.674576
100019750   HovMinajJackson 135 136 6022    0   28 Dec 2009 18:51:29 GMT    neverland
100020433   MattieBX    131 97  2610    0   28 Dec 2009 18:54:40 GMT    zundert
100024321   KatieStepek 64  93  503 0   28 Dec 2009 19:13:08 GMT    Hamilton
137179909   LaLovesU    431 499 19568   0   26 Apr 2010 01:45:05 GMT    Oakland,\   CA
```

The last line is one of the culprits I want to edit.

Comment: add a sample input and output for clarity as well as for others to test their solutions

Comment: My bad! Edited with an example and the issue at hand.

Comment: Note you can refer to the last field with `$NF`.

Comment: But if I use NF it'll return fields separated by spaces as well as tabs, and I dont care about spaces, they're fine. Or is there another wat you'd suggest using it?

Answer (score 1):

perhaps this is what you want?

```
$ seq 10 | paste -sd'\t'

1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10

$ seq 10 | paste -sd'\t' | sed 's/\t/ /7g'

1       2       3       4       5       6       7 8 9 10
```

I think only gnu-sed supports this though.  Also note, that `d'\t'` is already the default but just to emphasize that we're using tabs

**UPDATE**

To make this work on a tab delimited file row by row

```
$ sed 's/\t/ /7g' input.file > output.file
```

Comment: I installed Linux to try and use this because it looks like what I'd need, now I'm trying to use an input file instead of the seq 10, how do I do this? I'm trying to do

`paste -sd'\t' | sed 's/\t/ /7g' inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt`

But its not working, the command doesnt complete

Answer (score 0):

`awk` solution. I assumed that the tab is the field separator which is true in the example you have given. If the separator can either be tab or space, then you will have to use awk `split` function.

```
awk -F'\t' '{
    for (i=1; i < NF; i++) {     # iterator and print
        if (i < 7) {
            printf("%s ", $i)    # for <7 column, print space as separator
        } else {
            printf("%s\t", $i)   # for 7+ column, print as it is with tab
        }
    }
    print ""                     # print new line - record separator
}'
```

One-line solution:

```
awk -F'\t' '{for (i=1; i < NF; i++) { if (i < 7) { printf("%s ", $i) } else { printf("%s\t", $i)} }print ""}'
```